# Correct way to index email column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

So i'm working on a internet service and in my database i have a users table. I want to index the email column but i came across the problem of indexing strings of different length.

So i thought of a solution, 
I created another column of type int and before storing the user's record i converted his/her email into the sum of the ascii values of the characters of the email. I am only creating the sum when i know that nobody has used that same email in the past, so there is no chance of that string being same.

But i figuered that sum can still match other records. I want to know what are the chances of the sum being same for different emails.

If this works i can easily index a index column.

Here's the algorithm i'm using to convert email string to int.

```
String email="testing@test.com"; // Allowed characters: 0-9 A-B a-b + - . _

    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<email.length();i++){
        int ch=(int)email.charAt(i);
        if(ch>47 && ch<58){
            sum+=ch;
        }else if(ch>96 && ch<123){
            sum+=ch;
        }else if(ch>64 && ch<91){
            sum+=ch;
        }else if(ch==43 || ch==45 || ch==46 || ch==95 || ch==64){
            sum+=ch;
        }else{
            sum=0;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: what code language is that, Java? what does this have to do with what you're asking and the tags you used?

Comment: yes it is java.

Comment: i am just showing how i'm converting string to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we want to index an email address to make sure that there is no duplicate email address and hence user, than you cannot use a hash or sum, because you will have a collision some when.

Even if it is unlikely - it doesn’t mean that it can't happen. And when it happens - then nobody knows why the software doesn’t work - for that "collided user" or even worse a user can take over an account.

That's why, I would strongly recommend putting an database index on the email address, no matter what.

That's easy and works in all cases independently.

To create a table would avoid duplicates, and is easy to implement (keyword: "UNIQUE KEY"):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `email_address` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `email_address` (`email_address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci;
```

To test whether a record already exists is also easy:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE email_address = "abc@google.com"
```

According to fyrye's comment, the usage of the collation that I selected (ending with "ci", case insensitive) allows to store case sensitive. But will avoid inserting duplicate email_addresses that are just different cases (upper/lower).

Example: The table already contains a record with the email address "AbCd@mysql.com", then

```
INSERT INTO `db1080787-1`.`test` (
`email_address`
)
VALUES (
'abCd@mysql.com'
)
```

will lead to

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'abCd@mysql.com' for key 'email_address
```

Comment: There should be no need to manipulate the string when using a [`_ci` suffixed collation, as the data becomes case-insensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html). So using `WHERE email_address = 'ABC@google.com'` will also match `WHERE email_address = 'abc@google.com'`. Unless you change the collation on the column to be case-sensitive, or use `WHERE BINARY email_address = 'abc@google.com'` to force case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in indexing the email field itself. It may even be a partial index, size 10 or something close to that.

The sum of the ascii characters will result in many, many collisions. You would be better off hashing the email and storing the hash as binary or even as int.

Comment: what type of hash and how to convert it to binary or int. can you share an example or link

Comment: Any hash, md5 for example. You added the tag php in this question, in php the function `md5('string', true);` will return the md5 hash for the string as a binary.

But again, I don't see any problem in indexing the email field itself.

Comment: @EnricoDias Why hash the email address?

Comment: @duskwuff For some reason he doesn't want to index strings, so hashing is the next best thing in this case. Hashing is just better than the way of summing ascii values that he proposed.